# Proper way of extracting a slice from an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an helper function to slice an array which is supposed to return an array. It returns successfully but after executing the function over and over again, it starts returning numbers that are not the array indices. Kindly help as I am still learning.

Here is the slice function. I have also tried to make the `new_arr` static but I got a compile-constant error.

```
int *slice(int arr[], int beg, int end)
{
    int i;
    int *new_arr = malloc(sizeof(*new_arr)*sizeof(int));
    for(i=beg; i< end; i++)
    {
        new_arr[i] = arr[i];
        // printf("new_arr[%d] = %d\n",  i, arr[i]);
    }
    return new_arr;

}
```

Here is the `main`:

```
int main(void)
{
     int arr1[] = {2, -3, 3, 1, 10, 8, 2, 5, 13, -5, 3, -18};
     int arrSize = sizeof(arr1);
     int length = arrSize/sizeof(int);
     int div = length/4;
     int *winter;
     int *spring;
    //  int *summer;
    //  int *autumn;
     winter =  slice(arr1, 0, div);
     spring = slice(arr1, div, div*2);
    //  summer = slice(arr1, div*2, div*3);
    //  autumn = slice(arr1, div*3, div*4);



    //  int i;
     printf("%d", spring[1]);

    // printf("%d", arrSize);

}
```

I want the function to be consistent with the values inside the array.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(*new_arr)*sizeof(int))` is totally wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks I have also tried ```(int*) malloc(10*sizeof(int))```

Comment: You need to allocate enough space for `end - begin` integers — neither of the expressions shown for the size in the `malloc()` calls looks the slightest bit like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I can tell from the name of your function, you want to get a slice out of an existing array, by allocating a new array and copying the values from the original one.

Your function has some problems:

1. `malloc(sizeof(*new_arr)*sizeof(int))` is wrong, it's the same as `malloc(sizeof(int)*sizeof(int))`, which is incorrect and always allocates the same amount of space regardless of what you need.
2. You're iterating using `beg` and `end` without any bound check trusting the values on the newly allocated array, that's also wrong.
3. You're using `int` all around, which can cause problems for large or negative numbers, you should use `size_t` instead.

The right way to achieve what you want would be the following:

```
int *slice(int arr[], size_t beg, size_t end)
{
    size_t size, i;
    int *new_arr;

    size = end - beg;
    new_arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        new_arr[i] = arr[beg + i];

    return new_arr;
}
```

Comment: Since the `end` element isn't copied, the `+ 1` isn't needed, is it?  We can debate whether `if (new_arr == NULL) return NULL:` would be a good idea.  And using C99 or later, you could use `size_t size = end - beg; int *new_arr = malloc(size * sizeof(*new_arr)); for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) { … }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, I can only guess that from the way OP wants to slice it in four "seasons" of supposedly 4 elements... makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler With `beg == end`, would you expect  0 or 1 `int`?

Comment: @chux — since the question used `for (i = beg;  i < end; i++)`, it is possible to say that the answer should be 0 for `beg == end`.  I can also see a case for assuming that the `end` should be copied too — it isn't clear that the OP knows what is wanted.  It wouldn't be a bad idea to `assert(end >= begin):` or `assert(end > begin);`, which would clarify what's required.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True about lack of clarity.  Yet given `winter =  slice(arr1, 0, div);
     spring = slice(arr1, div, div*2);` it certainly like the last parameter should be "1 past" and not inclusive.

Comment: Those are all good points even though OP probably just `^C^V`'d the code and ran away.

Comment: UV for a good answer, although I would have gone with `new_arr = malloc(sizeof *new_arr * size);`

Comment: @chux I would at least put some parentheses around that `*new_arr`, looks confusing. `sizeof *var` in general looks confusing to me specially if the variable is far apart from it's declaration, makes me forget which type it is, even though I know that it's a more consistent and less error prone form.